# accessing templated member function of an object that is a member of a struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct, shared-ptr

So I have a structure which hold many members including a boost shared pointer to a PCLVisualizer object.  The PCLVisualizer class is a templated class with a member function updatePointcloud.  I am trying to call updatePointCloud for template PointType.  Please see code below:

```
template <typename PointType>
class A {
    struct gt_data_type {
        model_struct line;
        PointCloudTPtr input;
        PointCloudTPtr output;
        int step_size;
        int segment_min_pts;
        vector<float> directions;
        float current_direction;
        vector<line_segment> seeds;
        Eigen::Vector4f prev_vector;
        Eigen::Vector4f current_vector;
        Eigen::Vector4f p;
        typename pcl::search::KdTree<PointType>::Ptr tree;
        pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr viewer;
        line_segment prev_segment;

    };

    gt_data_type gt_data;


    void foo(PointCloudTPtr output) {
        pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("Track Viewer"));
        gt_data.output = output;
        gt_data.viewer = viewer;
        // next line causes compile error
        gt_data.viewer->updatePointCloud<PointType>(gt_data.output,"rail");
    }

}
```

Note that PointCloudTPtr is just a typedef for different shared_ptr.  I get the following error at the line indicated:
`expected primary-expression before '>' token`

If I omit the struct and call the viewer member function directly by doing this:
`viewer->updatePointCloud<PointType>(gt_data.output,"rail");`

my code compiles.  I don't understand why accessing the viewer through a struct makes any difference.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is a really bad simple case test... Do you attempt to use `gt_data` as a type, or do you have a variable named `gt_data` as well? How is `gt_data.output` declared, is it `static`? Is `gt_data` a template or dependent on a template parameter? You should prepare a simple minimal test case that reproduces the problem and post that...

Comment: @K-ballo thank you for pointing out the problems with my question.  I have made some changes.  I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: It doesn't clarify where `PointType` comes from, nor that `foo` is dependent on it... (since my answer solved your problem I can guess those out, but I shouldn't have to guess what your question is)

Comment: Now the question shows enough context to be actually answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample you posted should work fine. **Unless you actually meant to call `viewer` on a type instead of a variable**. However, if `gl_data` is itself a *template* or dependent on a *template parameter*, then the compiler wouldn't know if you are writing a function call or a comparison expression. And from the looks of your code, it seems that it is dependent on the template parameter `PointType`.

Just as `typename` is needed to disambiguate between a type and a variable, `template` is needed to disambiguate between a template and a comparison:

```
data.viewer->template updatePointCloud<PointType>(data.output,"rail");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that my problem.  I was just wondering why the compiler can disambiguate between a template and comparison when I  remove the struct from the call but it can't when I add the struct to the call?

Comment: @Mustafa: Because there is something else that you are not showing us... There is a template there somewhere

Comment: @Mustafa: Now that you have updated the question,  `typename` and `template` are only needed when there is a dependency on a template parameter. Otherwise, if the compiler knows the types before hand, it can actually go and see if what you are referring to is either a variable, a type, or a function.

Comment: ok, so I edited it again to show that the code that I am showing is actually part of a templated class.  So is the tree member what causes the struct to be dependent on template parameter?

Comment: @Mustafa: No, the actual type of the struct is `template< typename PointType > struct A< PointType >::gt_data_type`, which as you can clearly see is dependent on the template parameter `PointType`.

Answer (score 1):

You need an object ot type `gt_data` not the name of the class directly.

Comment: Presumably he has a variable named `gt_data`, since the second example compiles fine while doing `gt_data.output`.